# How to prevent file from commiting in git?

Tags: git

Is there any way to prevent some file from commiting?

Let's `Settings.h` contains some settings like this:

```
 #define SETTING1
 #define SETTING2
 //   Some other stuff
```

Sometimes, during my work I should disable some settings from this file. After completion task, I commit changes (before commiting I need revert changes in `Setting.h` file). History of changes can be long and I want to guard myself from accidential commiting changes in `Settings.h`.

EDIT: I want to track changes in `Settings.h` file, but all I want to prevent file from commiting changes on period of my work (forbid accidentially committing its changes)

Comment: [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) is your savior

Comment: .gitignore, just in case.

Comment: @OmriLuzon, but git will not track Settings.h file in such case, isn't? All I want is to prevent file from commiting changes on period of my work

Comment: @OmriLuzon, oh I understand, but what if I accidentially commit changes in gitignore file?

Comment: Actually .gitignore is useless here, because it has no effect on a file that's already in the index.

Answer (score 0):

if the file needs to be versioned but you have to make changes you can do this:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file_to_ignore>
```

Comment: Messing with the `assume-unchanged` or `skip-worktree` bits is almost always the wrong answer.  Pulls affecting the file will fail with misleading error messages.

Comment: Making assumptions is never a perfect answer. There are circumstances when this is a viable option as long as you are aware of the potential consequences. My answer would be better if I included that.

Answer (score -2):

Add `Setting.h` to `.gitignore` file.

Comment: This does not work. `.gitignore` only prevents untracked files from being committed. But what the OP is asking about is preventing committing of changes to an existing file. `.gitignore` will not prevent that.

Comment: It's a file that's already tracked; .gitignore will have no effect.